# boost::asio::deadline_timer NOT work correctly when change PC‘s system time

Tags: c++, boost, posix, boost-asio

The Code as fllow, it works fine when do nothing.
BUT, if you change PC's system time advice or delay when it running, it not work as I wanted.
It's use calendar, NOT tick.
So do have any method to solve this ? Or has any other timer class which boost provide ?

```
 void on_test_timer(const boost::system::error_code& err)
    {
         if(!err)
             printf("Hello\r\n");
    }    

    void main(){
      boost::asio::deadline_timer me;
      me.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::millisec(5000));
      me.async_wait(boost::bind(on_test_timer, _1));

      while(true){
         Sleep(10);
      } 
    }
```

Comment: this is what [steady_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/steady_timer.html) is for.